# Regular expression for Custom Decimal

Tags: java, regex

My definition of **Custom Decimal =>** The number can be represented as (p,s) where p is the precision and s is the scale and then describe everything with respect to precision and scale. Use Custom Decimal if you need to store decimals that have more than eight digits in the fractional part. Can have a maximum scale of 29 and a maximum precision of 30. The non-fractional part of the number can have a maximum of 29 digits.

P and S may vary...

Assume P= 18 S=12 i.e/ (P,S) = (18,12)

intLength = 12

fractionalLength=18

**Piece of code**

```
String regExprCD = "^-?\\d{1,"+intLength+"}(?>\\.\\d{0,"+fractionalLength+"})?$";

                    info("regExprCD = "+regExprCD );
                    if (value.matches(regExprCD ) || value.isEmpty()){
                        Window.alert("Valid CUSTOM_DECIMAL value");
                    }else{
                        Window.alert("Valid CUSTOM_DECIMAL value");
                    }
```

I tried following regular Expression but error comes on page **"Syntax error in regular expression"**

**`^-?\\d{1,"+intLength+"}(?>\\.\\d{0,"+fractionalLength+"})?$`**

Which is perfect regular expression to allow following cases :

**Regular expression should accept following Custom Decimal:**

123456789012345678

1234567.1234567890

1.123456789012

1234567890.1234567

12345678901234567.

12345.

**Regular expression should not accept following Custom Decimal:**

12345678901234567890 : Reason P > 18 :: P should not be greater than 18

1234567.1234567890123 : Reason s>12 : :: S should not be greater than 12

.1 or .1232 :: Invalid

I used **`^-?\\d{1,"+intLength+"}(?>\\.\\d{0,"+fractionalLength+"})?$`**  this regular expression.

This regular expression working fine in Sample java program. Not working in GWT

Throwing error on web page (developed in GWT) :: "Syntax error in regular expression"

what should be data type of intLength  and fractionalLength ? int or string ?

**Which is perfect regular expression ?**

Any help or guidance in this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: `12345678.1234567890` shouldn't match because the expression is something like `\d{1,7}\.\d{1,10}`, right? What I mean, the reason is the maximum length of the integer or fraction part is violated, correct? Could you also show us which test cases didn't work correctly? Or are the second group of examples those that _should_ match but don't using your expression?

Comment: RegEx should accepted Custom Decimal:

@ 123456789012345678 Pass

@ 1234567.1234567890 pass

@ 1.123456789012 pass

@ 1234567890.1234567 pass

@ 12345678901234567. fail :( Expected to pass this case

@ 12345.   fail :( Expected to pass this case

Comment: Look at my answer, the expression there should match `12345.`.

Comment: this `1234567890.1234567` appears in both allowed and disallowed; why exactly is `1234567.1234567890` allowed but `12345678.1234567890` disallowed ?

Comment: @Thomas @ 12345678.1234567890 

@ 1234567.12345678901

@ 1.123456789012

@ 1234567890.1234567 [#2] RegExpr matching :( Expected should not match this case

Comment: Please update your question and to each number that should not match you should add the reason why. It's really hard to get why certain numbers should match and others wouldn't. If it is just the length, then what lengths did you put into the expression?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this expression: `^-?\d{0,x}(?>\.\d{0,y})?$` which should match any number starting with an optional minus, then up to `x` digits, followed by a dot and up to `y` digits.

`x` and `y` would be your `intLength` and `fractionalLength`.

If you want to make the integer or fraction part a requirement (such that `.1` or `1.` don't match), just replace the zero in the number interval with a 1, i.e. `^-?\d{1,x}(?>\.\d{1,y})?$`.

*Update*:

Here's a SSCCE with fixed lengths:

```
String expression = "^-?\\d{1,18}(?>\\.\\d{0,12})?$";

//prints true
System.out.println("12345678".matches(expression)); 

//prints true
System.out.println("1234.5678".matches(expression)); 

//prints false -> integer part too long
System.out.println("1234567890123456789.5678".matches(expression)); 

//prints false -> fraction part too long
System.out.println("1234.1234567890123".matches(expression)); 

//prints false -> integer part missing
System.out.println(".5678".matches(expression));
```

Comment: Your regular expression throwing error on GWT page :"Syntax error in regular expression"

Comment: @VaibhaV can you provide more details on the expression? It works for me when I use `"^-?\\d{1,12}(?>\\.\\d{0,18})?$"`. Can you provide the output of the `info(...)` statement?

Comment: See my output of info statement --> `regExprCD = ^-?\d{1,18}(?>\.\d{0,12})?$`

Comment: Your regular expression `regExprCD = ^-?\d{1,18}(?>\.\d{0,12})?$` working fine in sample GWT demo But I dont know why It is not working in main GWT application :(

Answer (score 0):

Try : ^[\d]{1,3}[.]{1}[\d]{1,1}|^[\d]{1,3}

```
public class RegexTestStrings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] EXAMPLE_TEST = {"123", "0", "123.4", ".1", "123.", "12a", "a12"};
        int P= 4, S=1;
        for(int i = 0; i< EXAMPLE_TEST.length; i++){
            System.out.println(EXAMPLE_TEST[i]+" -- "+EXAMPLE_TEST[i].matches("^[\\d]{1,"+(P-S)+"}[.]{1}[\\d]{1,"+(S)+"}|^[\\d]{1,"+(P-1)+"}"));    
        }
    }
}
```

Result :

```
123 -- true
0 -- true
123.4 -- true
.1 -- false
123. -- false
12a -- false
a12 -- false
```